# Docker container is not updating on code change

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs

EDITED.Resolved

So I created default nest.js project with `nest new project` command in terminal.
In root folder I created files:

Dockerfile

```
# Base image
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./


FROM base AS dev

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4250
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]


FROM base AS prod

RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:prod" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: dev
    ports:
      - 4250:4250
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
```

.dockerignore

```
node_modules
dist
.git
.env
docker.env
```

Then I ran command `docker-compose up` , and as a result in CLI I have messages:
[image: Starting compilation in watch mode]

I can now test application with postman, or just open localhost:4250 in browser, yet on changes in code container does not rebuild.
How to fix it?

PS. This is the most simplistic version of docker configs, I plan to build up / optimise on it, but first I need to fix problem with updates not been registered.

Comment: Do you need Docker for this setup at all?  Docker's filesystem isolation feature can cause trouble trying to simulate a local live-reloading environment, and I frequently see SO questions that it doesn't work.  Can you use Node without Docker here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Container created with docker-compose up doesn\`t update on code change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75561698/container-created-with-docker-compose-up-doesnt-update-on-code-change)

Comment: Don't edit the title to mark the question `RESOLVED`. If the solution was in a comment and nobody bothers to write it as an answer, write the answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an unused block of code:

FROM base AS dev

```
# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4250
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
```

coment it or do the build there and copy it to the next step.

To rebuild the container do a `docker-compose up --build`